# Reflection optimizations with attributes . 

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Is there a way in C# to:

1. Get all the properties of a class that have attributes on them (versus having to loop through all properties and then check if attribute exists.
2. If i want all Public, Internal, and Protected properties but NOT private properties, i can't find a way of doing that.  I can only do this:

   PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)

Is there a way to avoid getting private properties but do get everything else.

Comment: Private properties? The point of properties is to expose your private instance fields. Not sure why you would want private properties in the first place.

Comment: I DONT want private properties . .that is the question of how to AVOID it looking at private properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to do either of these.

Just how many types do you have to reflect over, though? Is it really a bottleneck? Are you able to cache the results to avoid having to do it more than once per type?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding caching: if you access properties via `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` then you get caching for free. The `TypeDescriptor` class has some other nice utility methods for reflection situations like this. It only operates on `public` properties though (no `protected` or `internal` members, and no fields).

Comment: The caching with TypeDescriptor is actually quite limited, partly because it has to deal with scenarios like extension properties.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to do it any *quicker* - but what you can do is do it less often by caching the data. A generic utility class can be a handy way of doing this, for example:

```
static class PropertyCache<T>
{
    private static SomeCacheType cache;
    public static SomeCacheType Cache
    {
        get
        {
            if (cache == null) Build();
            return cache;
        }
    }
    static void Build()
    {
        /// populate "cache"
    }
}
```

Then your PropertyCache.Cache has the data just for Foo, etc - with lazy population. You could also use a static constructor if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

In response to (2): If you're outside of the class/assembly in question, `internal` and `protected` are the same as `private`.

If you want to access these, you'll need to ask for all properties, as you've already done, and filter the list yourself.